# Update the style of javascript Confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

How to update the style of javascript Confirm box in the below example, e.g. using jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteRow(tableName,colName,id, obj){ 
    var r=confirm("Delete row from table " + tableName + " having " + colName+ " " +id+ "?" );
    if (r==true) {
           $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "callpage.php?page=tables/delete.php",
                   data: "tableName=" + tableName + "&colName=" + colName + "&id=" + id,
                   success: function(msg){
                     if(msg === '1'){
                        obj = $(obj).parents('tr');
                        $(obj).slideUp().remove();
                     }
                     else
                         alert("Error.");
                   }
            });

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the box itself, but there are plenty of good plugins that acts like a normal confirm-box.

https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+confirm+box+plugin

I've had some great experience with jConfirmAction (http://www.webappers.com/2010/05/10/jconfirmaction-a-jquery-plugin-for-confirmation-box/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The confirm box is created by the browser.

There are many scripts available, some of them jQuery plugins, to create modal dialogues in the page with fixed-positioned `<div>`s. Note that they will return the user's choice asynchronously (in a callback).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The window shown by `prompt()` is rendered by the platform.

You'd need to use a custom modal one with a callback, as you can't emulate the blocking nature  in the browser and still receive the button events.